# Lecture notes competitive labor market with minimum wage

Tags: microeconomics, labor-economics, theory, competitive-equilibrium

Can somebody recommend lecture notes that derive competitive labour market model equilibrium with minimum wages? This has been surprisingly hard to find, because most lecture notes use minimum wages to introduce the monopsony model, as for instance does the Labor Economics textbook by Cahuc et al (2014).

Comment: You may be interested in this book: https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691025872/labor-demand. I am not sure it contains what you are asking for but: (1) it does deal with labor demand models (2) it is often referred to so I think it is an authoritative source (Borjas for example refers to it and he is pretty influential when t comes to labor and immigration) (3) It does contain analysis of minimum wage policies.

Comment: Thanks, I ll look into it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Varian textbook Intermediate Microeconomics (I am guessing in most micro textbooks), the chapter on Equilibrium discusses price controls in the presence of a demand and supply function. You can apply that discussion directly to the (competitve) labor market, were the price of labor is of course the wage.